# Anchor links wih NavBar Issue

Tags: html

I have a navbar which is hiding the anchor links when you click on them.
Example can be seen here

https://www.fir3net.com/Firewalls/Cisco/cisco-asa-83-nat.html#Intro

Basically the code is,

```
<span style="color: #000000;">
    <a href="#Intro">
        <span style="color: #000000;">1. Introduction
        </span> 
    </a>
</span>

<h2 class="h3">
    <span style="color: #000000;">
        <strong>
             <a name="Intro">
                  <span style="color:#000000;">Introduction
                  </span>
             </a>
        </strong>
    </span>
</h2>
```

EDIT : You can see the problem when you go to https://www.fir3net.com/Firewalls/Cisco/cisco-asa-83-nat.html and then click Introduction. Your see the header hidden under the navbar.

Comment: The h2 title is hidden by the navbar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work. 
NOTE[please add name tag to other div also to make full navigation work for now only first link is working.]

```
    jQuery(".contents span a").click(function() {
    var des = jQuery(this).attr('href');
     var desName = "name='"+des.substring(1, des.length)+"'";
   alert(desName);
    jQuery('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: jQuery("["+desName+"]").offset().top-50
    }, 2000);
});
```

Comment: Is there no way outside of Jquery ?

Comment: yes we can you need to give reference to any other element that is 50px down to the given reference